# "Unresolvable dependency resolving" Laravel error

Tags: php, laravel, backend

So I was just following a tutorial and wrote this piece of code:

```
Route::get('/search', function (Request $request) {
    dd($request);
});
```

and when I went to the (/search?name=HelloWorld) route it gave me this error:

`Unresolvable dependency resolving [Parameter #0 [ <required> string $method ]] in class GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request`

I'm still new to this so I'm not exactly sure what's the issue.

Comment: I just tested your code on fresh install of Laravel 10 and it works fine. run `composer update` and `composer dump-autoload`, then try again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to use the laravel Request class from this namespace
`use Illuminate\Http\Request;` instead of `use  GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request;`